# Disorganization in vector drawable icons, after update gradle in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, vector

There are some vector drawable icons in my android application. I used gradle 3.0.1 in project gradle. Android studio suggests to update it to 3.1.2, then some of vector drawable icons disorganized as shown in the picture. How can resolve this?
[image: before & after]